# Merging rows and concatenating one column's data

Tags: microsoft-excel, merge, concatenation

I have a report with four data columns (see attached rows 1-9). I'm trying to merge any cells that have the same ExpDate and AccountName, and have the Type include all data. I've seen examples where you can sum a field (using pivot tables), but I want to concanate the data, not sum it.

(For my purposes, the names in Code field are irrelevant, they will always match if AccountName matches.)

It needs to look like is in rows 13/14.

[image: IMAGE OF WORKSHEET]

I have tried a pivot table, but can't seem to figure out how to join the TYPE data.

Comment: A pivot table will not do this.  You need to use vba or power query.

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239).

Comment: If you have Office 365 or 2021 you may consider using UNIQUE, TEXTJOIN etc to get a possible formula based solution. TEXTJOIN is available in earlier version but not UNIQUE function though.

Answer (score 0):

A power query might be more effective, but here's just one formula based solution. A bit inconvenient to maintain multiple formulas though!!

[image]

[image]

[image]

See above sample screenshots.

UNIQUE formula (Only available in Office 365 & 2021) in Cell I3 will simplify getting UNIQUE rows from first two columns. Of course if you do not have Office 365, **Remove Duplicates** from Data ribbon can be used, but it will not be a formula base approach.

Formula in K3 (array formula must be completed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar)

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF($D$4:$D$11=I3,IF($E$4:$E$11=J3,$F$4:$F$11,""),""))
```

Drag it down up to intended rows.

Array Formula (must be completed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar) in L3

```
=INDEX($G$4:$G$11,MATCH(I3&J3,$D$4:$D$11&$E$4:$E$11,0))
```

Hope this helps. Power Query may be alternative approach. Wait for others to respond on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365 you can use the FILTER() function for the text1, text2... arguments of TEXTJOIN(). The formula in C13 would be:

`=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER($C$2:$C$9,($A$2:$A$9=A11)*($B$2:$B$9=B11)))`

If you want to populate the unique date/account fields in columns A:B automatically you can use `=UNIQUE(A2:B9)` in cell A13